# Mobile: Mobile App makes one vs. two parallel requests?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, request, latency

We use GooglePlaces in our Mobile Android / iPhone App to donwload nearby stores.
In addition we have stores in our database that we want to show to the user.

Right now, as soon as our mobile app has a position, it fires two http-request, one to GooglePlaces and one to our server. As soon as both requets are finished, the app constructs a combined list and shows it to the user. We are talking about 50 Kb total in both requests.

We are thinking about just doing one request to our server. Our own server would then do the request to GooglePlaces, combines the two lists, and sends both back to the mobile client.
The advantage would be that our mobile app just needs to fire one request, but there might be an added latency when our server connects to googleplaces.

Testing the second option would take propably a whole day for us. Has anyone else run into a similiar issue? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

It is a trade-off, but we had a similar issues -- our app made independent requests (not to googleplaces, but other APIs), and we eventually converted to a single request model.  The advantages for us went beyond reducing the number of app requests.

1. The biggest factor that caused us to change was that the API we were using deployed a change with relatively short notice.  This required us to make the changes to the code and redeploy the app.  Still, there were those that did not update and sent support requests wondering why the app stopped working as intended.  In the single request model, we are able to avoid these updates (and associated support issues). When the upstream data provider changes in the API, we handle the conversion to our internal format on the server.
2. Related to 1) we have been able to incorporate additional sources of data without updating the app.  As we locate new sources of data that fit into our existing model, we can deploy them without an app update.
3. We are able to cache some of of our requests on the server.  Your requests might be too local and you need to check if caching is allowed by the TOS, but for us, we've been able to mitigate some of the latency by caching results. It has also allowed us to graceful degrade during an API outage.
4. We were able to optimize the data before sending it to the device.  We filter out any data elements we know are not used by the app on the server and optimize the xml so the download size is decreased by 20%-30%.